# Hadoop: namenode/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode and namenode:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview pages show only 2 active nodes out of 3

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, webhdfs

I have setup a fully distributed `hadoop` system with `ubuntu`. I have my host system and then 2 VirtualBox installed on that. 
When I execute `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` from master node, `datanode` gets started on all 3 systems. I can see that using `jps`. But when I try to verify using web UI, it shows only 2 active nodes. One of `datanode` installed on one VM is not visible there at all.
Any bug with UI or some other issue?

Comment: This is because datanode in VM couldn't communicate with your namenode. Check the logs.